# How to use Where and Orderby to firestore in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to filter Fruits items with its order, but these are diffrent field. How can use the `whereEqualto` and `orderBy`?

is there any idea to do this?

```
mStore.collection("All-ar").whereEqualTo("type","Fruits").orderBy("order").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            for (DocumentSnapshot doc:task.getResult().getDocuments()){
                Items items = doc.toObject(Items.class);
                mItemsList.add(items);
                itemsRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are not setting the adapter and also the `itemsRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` is inside the loop. Try this code:

```java
mStore.collection("All-ar").whereEqualTo("type","Fruits").orderBy("order").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            for (DocumentSnapshot doc:task.getResult().getDocuments()){
                                Items items = doc.toObject(Items.class);
                                mItemsList.add(items);
                            }
                        }
                        itemsRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
```

Maybe that is why you don't see the fruits ordered. (Answered according to what I understood).

Comment: no point in setting an adapter repeatedly

Comment: @a_local_nobody  But he is using `.get()`.  he is not using event listener

Comment: OP is asking about firebase specifically, nothing regarding adapters, so unless we can rule out everything else to the point where OP would have to provide more info, we can assume they've set the adapter already

Comment: OP is already calling `itemsRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` inside of their loop, which is probably inefficient but won't be the reason why data won't be showing, right ? so realistically your answer could just be a comment at this point, at best you're now just optimizing irrelevant code which OP didn't ask about

Comment: @a_local_nobody my answers is based on the thing that he might not be setting the adapter. That is why I felt I could answer it here. But, if u want me to add it as a comment, I can do so now. Waiting for responce

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to filter on two fields?

That should be something like:

```
mStore.collection("All-ar")
  .whereEqualTo("type","Fruits")
  .whereEqualTo("order", 152)
  .get()
  ...
```